# Merge two EmailMessage in C#

Tags: c#, email, system.net.mail

What is the correct way to merge two EmailMessage. I tried following:

```
mergedMessage.Body.Text = message1.Body.Text + message2.Body.Text
```

But it is creating two html tags in the merged message, which is not correct.

Should I parse the `message1.Body.Text` and `message2.Body.Text` and fetch the content of html and copy to the `mergedMessage`?

Comment: `Should I parse the message1.Body.Text and message2.Body.Text and fetch the content of html and copy to the mergedMessage?` Yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<.*?>";

static string StripHTML (this string inputString)
{
   return Regex.Replace 
     (inputString, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
}


mergedMessage.Body.Text = message1.Body.Text.StripHTML()  + message2.Body.Text.StripHTML()
```